# Complexity of numerical 3-dimensional matching where the three multisets are identical

Tags: np-hardness

Consider the following problem:

- Input: one multiset $S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}$ of positive integers written in unary
- Output: can we build $n$ triples that sum to the same value, using each element of $S$ in each component exactly once. Formally, does there exist permutations $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \sigma_3$ of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ such that, for each $1 \leq i \leq n$, we have $s_{\sigma_1(i)} + s_{\sigma_2(i)} + s_{\sigma_3(i)} = B$ for some value $B$. (Note that, if a solution exists, then necessarily $B = \frac{3}{n} \sum_i s_i$, implying that there can only be a solution if that quantity is an integer.)

This problem is clearly in NP. **Is it NP-complete?**

This problem is equivalent to the [numerical 3-dimensional matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_3-dimensional_matching) problem, which is NP-hard, but I have added the constraint that the three multisets $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ in the matching must be identical. I did not find related work studying this case.
The problem is also a stronger version of the problem in [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52453/is-this-a-known-problem-and-is-it-np-complete) by imposing $m=3$ and requiring that the numbers are given in unary. Last, it is related to the NP-hard [3-partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-partition_problem), but the multiset that we are partitioning consists of 3 parts that are identical and where each triple must use one element from each part. I am not sure if the problem is still NP-hard under these restrictions, or if it somehow becomes tractable.